# UIButton select state's image appears behind normal state's image

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I have a UIButton which has images set for both Normal and Selected State. From what I understand, when you switch the button.selected state to YES / NO, it should toggle between the two images. It sure does. But the selected state image always apear **behind** the normal state one.

The reason I can see this is because my normal state is a play button and the middle triangle is basically transparent. I can see the pause button appear behind it.

Anyone know what the problem is and, maybe how to fix it?

Thanks :)

Comment: I have the same problem with iOS 5.0. In my case there is a chance it happens the first time a NIB loads. On subsequent loads of the same NIB the button works fine until the application is terminated. I have sent a bugreport to Apple and would encourage anyone else experiencing this bug to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it by not using state variable to do it. I'm just explicitly setting the image each time. Kinda lame but works.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and it may be a bug so I will be checking with Apple.  I had the following code, yet the "Selected State" Image and Text would not display.

```
[btnConfirm setSelected: YES];
[btnConfirm setEnabled: NO];
[btnConfirm setAlpha: .6];
```

So if the item had been previously confirmed, I didn't want the user to be able to tap the button again (`[btnConfirm setEnabled: NO]`). I wanted the wording to change for CONFIRM to CONFIRMED, and I wanted a custom Checkmark image to be displayed as well.  Finally I wanted the button to appear "Grayed-Out" (`[btnConfirm setAlpha: .6]`).

Well this didn't work until I removed the `[btnConfirm setEnabled: NO]` statement.  For some reason when the button is Disabled it can't have a "Selected" state. I guess it makes sense, but why are they mutually exclusive, I can't explain, so I will report my issue.  in the mean time I may also try Highlighted...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by just using the Disabled state.  I removed the [btnConfirm setSelected: YES] because its no longer needed.  The Disabled state of the button is automatically set once the btnConfirm.Enabled is set to NO.

This resolved all of my issues.